# grep two strings from a file and write into a txt

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Could you please help me how to grep two strings (or the whole lines) from one file and write them on the same line in output file?

```
grep -e "string1 string2" inputfile > output.txt doesn't work
```

for one string it works:

```
grep -e "string1" inputfile > output.txt
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your grep command like below,

```
grep -o 'string1\|string2' file | paste - - > out.txt
```

This writes `string1 string2` in a single line on `out.txt`

Comment: yes it works, only I have to use -e except of -o to grep the whole line, thx

Comment: yep, remove `-o` to grep the whole line.

Comment: The current solution is almost equivalent to `echo "string1 string2" > out.txt` :D